# migrating from dropbox to onedrive

Tags: sharepoint, dropbox

**Senario**

We are migrating files from dropbox to onedrive. We download the top-level parent folders from dropbox and upload to onedrive. Those parent folders have many levels of subfolders and so on, so there are many files

Both dropbox and onedrive are on business version.

**Problem**

However, after upload is complete, we noticed some of the files in onedrive is very small, only a few KB, some are 0 KB. When download and open, they are blank.

**Investigation**

1. I located one of those blank files in dropbox. It is fine with full size
2. I upload to onedrive from dropbox folder in file explorer by drag and drop. The file uploaded successfully, and with the right size, and opens correctly

**Challenges**

I believe the issue only happens, when bulk upload a folder with many files/sub-folders in it. They all appear to be uploaded, but some of them got 0 byes, or corrupted. Of course, I can't upload them one by one, there are too many.

What would be your suggestions?

Comment: You do not name the tool you are using for the copy. If you are simply dragging and dropping with Windows Explorer, I would suggest that you research Robocopy, a robust command-line file copy utility that comes with Windows.

Comment: Which tool do you use to transfer files?
You can use rclone, which is a powerful tool for syncing files between multiple storage types.
Rclone offers a command to sync a source folder to a destination with integrity verification: https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_sync/